# how to save images in png using MITK

Tags: image, image-processing, medical, nifti, mitk

Hi i am uisng MITK Workbench 2016.11.0. I want to save image in PNG or JPEG or TIFF using MITK. But there are only 5 options available: NRRD, NIFTI, VTK, VTK LEGACY IMAGE. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Only 2-d images can be saved in classic 2-d image formats such as PNG, BMP, JPEG, or TIFF and only if the pixel format is supported by the image format.

If you seem to have a 2-d image for which the 2-d options are not available, it's most probably a 3-d image with a single slice. A 3-d image can't be saved as 2-d image even with a single slice as important 3-d meta-data like 3-d origin and orientation in 3-d space would be lost.

Comment: Yes i have 3d images with 2d slices. Is there is any other way to save 3d images with each 2d slices.